# Sorting Attributes of Xml

Tags: c#, xml

My input is as a such as the blew Xml:

```
<Phrase Entry="ID">
 <Ans number="1">
  <Identification LastName="Bornery" Name="John" Age="23"/>
 </Ans>
</Phrase>
```

and I want to sort the Xml attributes base on their first character Names order by 
alphabetic arrangment such as the blew Xml:

```
<Phrase Entry="ID">
 <Ans number="1">
  <Identification Age="23" LastName="Bornery" Name="John" />
 </Ans>
</Phrase>
```

thanks.

Comment: `LastName` is not attribute. Its an element name. Your XML has a wrong syntax.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Attribute order is unimportant for any compliant parser...

Comment: @MarcGravell perhaps for human brains reading the xml?

Comment: Your question is good. Because I want to compare this Xml with another Xml that is the second of them is arranged.

Comment: I have an example where the order matters. I have XML data stored in a Git repository. The library that creates it puts the attributes in random order. This means that a git diff results in hundreds of lines with "changes" and so I cannot tell how the data differ between the two files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your output xml is wrong but if input was like so:

```
<Phrase Entry="ID">
 <Ans number="1">
  <Blah LastName="Bornery" Name="John" Age="23"/>
 </Ans>
</Phrase>
```

Then the following code

```
static string SortAttributes(string xml)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants())
    {
        var attrs = element.Attributes().ToList();
        attrs.Remove();
        attrs.Sort((a, b) => a.Name.LocalName.CompareTo(b.Name.LocalName));
        element.Add(attrs);
    }
    xml = doc.ToString();
    return xml;
}
```

Will return this

```
<Phrase Entry="ID">
  <Ans number="1">
    <Blah Age="23" LastName="Bornery" Name="John" />
  </Ans>
</Phrase>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare two XML documents as strings, you should convert them into Canonical XML. This involves much more than getting the attributes into a canonical order: it involves, for example, normalising whitespace and perhaps namespace prefixes. Look for an XML canonicalization utility.